CURL Failed to connect to example.com port 443: Timed out
I'm trying to send some XML data using CURL in a foreach loop.
Data is getting passed sometimes with a success response also TIMEDOUT error sometimes.
foreach($contents as $key=>$val){

   $dataCD='';
   $dataCD.="<arg0>
   *some data*
  </arg0>";
  $data="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ws=\"http://example.com/\">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>";
  $data.=$dataCD;
  $data.="</soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>";   
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    //live
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com",
    
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,

    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: text/xml","User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0"),
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60, // Increase the timeout to 60 seconds
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,  // Timeout to establish connection
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true, // Enable verbose output
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
  ));
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  // $text= $data;
  if($err)
  {
    $logs = '[ '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()).']   [ error  ] '.$err."\r\n"; 
    $logfile = fopen('E:\xampp\htdocs\project\errors_test.log','a','1');
    fwrite($logfile, $logs);
    fclose($logfile);
  }
}

I'm getting below error for few data

[ 2024-09-05 11:09:31]   [ error ] Failed to connect to example.com
port 443: Timed out

I've included below option to increase timeout too.

CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,  CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,

Looking for some suggestions, thanks in advance.

Have you tried moving the curl_init and curl_close part outside the loop?

How often does it fail?  Connections should complete in a few seconds.  When they fail it usually means the server isn't running (or running very slow).  Port 443 is HTTPS and if certificate is not loaded properly it could result in a timeout.  But if certificate is bad it would fail every time.  You may be going through a proxy and the proxy is giving intermittent results.
